Plutonium production in the movie "Oppenheimer"
In the movie "Oppenheimer", we see a bomb design meeting at Los Alamos, where the attendees are informed in demonstrative fashion about the current availability of fissile materials:

For a bomb based on U-235, the project needs to obtain a fishbowl-sized amount, and currently only the equivalent of a handful of marbles has been refined.

For a bomb based on Pu-239, the project needs to obtain a cognac-glass-sized amount, and currently only the equivalent of a three marbles has been refined.


A bit later in the movie, Oppenheimer is shown visiting the first nuclear pile in history ("pile" as in "heap", as named by Fermi), Enrico Fermi's Chicago Pile-1, set up under the original Stagg Football Field of the University of Chicago here. (And for this, nuclear-grade graphite had to be conceived of and produced first, a fascinating story indeed.)
However, it so happens to be the case that you cannot produce any Plutonium without first having a pile. You need a pile to breed Pu-239 from U-238, and then the Plutonium can be chemically isolated from the "used Uranium". This breeding and chemical refinement process was scaled up to industrial levels at Hanford, Washington, which is a superfund site that needs another USD 300 billion or so to clean up to this day.
So these two scenes seem to be in reverse order, in fact it would be some time before the first plutonium would be produced: apparently that was only done in February 1945.
Did I miss something about Plutonium production or did Nolan take extreme liberties for expository reasons?

Cyclotron bombardment?  It didn't produce the quantities needed by Los Alamos to build a bomb, but smaller quantities were adequate for experiments that informed theories, which, in turn would guide further experiments.

Can't Oppenheimer have visited the pile after people mentioning they have said amounts? Nothing in your question suggests these scenes have to be in a specific order, just the existence of both things (first pile, then amount).

@Joachim Hmm... as this is a Nolan movie, it's possible, but I suppose the "colored" scenes are all supposed to happen in movie order.

But that doesn't address my concern: Oppenheimer could have visited the pile after the necessary amounts had already been refined, right?

@Joachim I don't think so because the "pile" did not generate anything of use - it was running at Watt level. Necessary amounts seem to have come from Hanford. The trick is to have a really large graphite pile through which you cycle U-238 / U-235 cylinders, and you actually throw the massive amount of heat away, into the nearby river. That's the British "Windscale" reactor at least, through which the Brits nearly managed to transform Scotland into an early Chernobyl when a fire broke out. Luckily M. Cockcroft had insisted on filters ...
